# Gaussian curvature of a Riemann surface is non-positive

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In the page 79 of Griffiths' and Harris' *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* it says that the curvatures satisfy
$$ \Theta_S\leq \Theta_E|_S,\quad \Theta_Q\geq \Theta_E|_Q $$
for $E$ a Hermitian bundle, $S\subset E$ a holomorphic subbundle and $Q$ the quotient bundle.

If $M\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ is a complex submanifold, for example, a Riemann surface, whose metric is induced from the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $\Theta_M\leq \Theta_{\mathbb{C}^n}|_M = 0$. If $\Phi$ is the associated $(1,1)$-form then $\sqrt{-1}\Theta=K\Phi$ where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature (page 77 of Griffiths-Harris). Since $\Phi$ is positive, we must have $K\leq 0$.

My question is, if we take $M$ to be the Riemann sphere, then it has positive Gaussian curvature, which contradicts $K\leq 0$, so what is the problem here?

Comment: One guess: the round metric is induced from $\Bbb R^3$, not $\Bbb C^2$. So nothing here should apply.

Comment: The Riemann sphere cannot be holomorphically embedded into $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see why this can not apply :)

Comment: Why Riemann sphere cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: @Camford No compact complex manifold can be embedded into $\Bbb C^n$. The coordinate projections of $\Bbb C^n$ restricted to the compact manifold are holomorphic and bounded, hence constant. The only compact complex submanifolds of $\Bbb C^n$ are points. This is the reason why $\Bbb C P^n$ is more natural in this setting.

Comment: Thank you!! I learn a lot from you!!

Comment: @string Although not _directly_ relevant to the question, but the existence of a holomorphic embedding into some $\mathbb{C}^n$ is equivalent to the complex manifold being Stein -- Stein manifolds generalize domains of holomorphy in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and have a rich theory. In fact, they are the transcendental cousins of affine manifolds in the GAGA string of analogies.